# C# Dynamic - "RuntimeBinderException"

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamictype

I am initializing dynamic with ExpandoObject and adding some items to it.

```
        dynamic dy = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
        dy.Property2 = new List<string>();
        dy.Property2.Add("Two");
        dy.Property2.Insert(0, "Zero");
        var coll1 = (List<string>)dy.Property2;
        var element = coll1.ElementAt(0);
```

above code works fine. but exception is thrown if replace last two statement with code mention below

```
        var data = dy.Property2.ElementAt(0);
```

exception is 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'ElementAt'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And it's absolutely right - `List<T>` *doesn't* have an `ElementAt` method. It only works in your original code because it's an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`. Dynamic typing doesn't let you call extension methods using the "special" syntax - but you can call it as a normal static method call:

```
var data = Enumerable.ElementAt(dy.Property2, 0);
```

Comment: On MSDN for dynamic its written "
The type is a static type, but an object of type dynamic bypasses static type checking. In most cases, it functions like it has type object" Can you please explain, need to understand ??

Comment: @slashshogdhe: Not in a comment thread, no. There's a *huge* amount to be said about `dynamic` (I wrote a whole chapter on it in C# in Depth) - it's really not appropriate to go into details within comments.

Comment: Placed a question on stackoverflow, please help now.